# Why Cocoa design patterns not representing best practices on Apple documentation anymore?

Tags: ios, cocoa-design-patterns

I just would like to know why from the official documentation of Apple, the common cocoa design patterns used doesn't represent the best practices to develop apps.

From https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW25

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: think of them as an diplomats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has simply reorganized their documentation and there's no longer a document exactly like the one you linked to. That one is in the legacy section, which is really just a graveyard of documents that are no longer current.

Many of the concepts discussed in the legacy document you linked to are now in [Concepts in Objective-C Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Introduction/Introduction.html). It has articles on MVC, delegates, target-action, etc. Also see [Cocoa Core Competencies](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html).

If you feel the current documentation is lacking relative to the older documentation, click the Feedback button in the lower right of any documentation page. Or file a bug in Apple's bug reporter.

Answer (score 0):

the document is just old and not guaranteed to be correct -- but also not guaranteed to be wrong :D

Thats just a generic disclaimer